# 'dpkg-deb' not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: linux-mint, dpkg

Cannot delete or install anything with apt, on both my own user and the root. Whenever I try I get the following error:

```
dpkg: warning: 'dpkg-deb' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

I checked the $PATH variable (in root as well my own user) and it contains everything it should contain:

```
ranran9991@Ran-Mint ~ $ sudo -i
[sudo] password for ranran9991: 
Ran-Mint ~ # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin
```

Output of `grep -i path /etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

Output of `sudo find / -mount -name dpkg-deb -exec ls -ld {} +`

```
ranran9991@Ran-Mint ~ $ sudo find / -mount -name dpkg-deb -exec ls -ld {} +
[sudo] password for ranran9991: 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Nov 24  2018 /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dpkg-deb -> dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153952 Oct  4  2018 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8c4b3545f8b2b1fd424a8054dfa0a631959619f0dc34efe9ca5c5e52f0fe7696/diff/usr/bin/dpkg-deb
```

I am using Cinnamon Mint 18.3.

I am unsure what to do and would love some help.

Comment: What is result of running `sudo find / -mount -name dpkg-deb -exec ls -ld {} +` please. (On my Debian systems I see `/usr/bin/dpkg-deb` with the corresponding file details. On your system I'm half expecting to see it but with the wrong permissions.)

Comment: Can you run `dpkg`? If so, try `# dpkg -C`. That's the audit command. If you can't run `dpkg`, something is very badly wrong, and you should focus on getting `dpkg` back. If it can't find `dpkg`, do a `ls -la /usr/bin/dpkg`. If that is missing, then you need to replace it. And do you recall doing anything out of the ordinary with your system that might have caused it to break?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I can run dpkg --help normally, dpkg -C writes nothing to the console for me.  /usr/bin/dpkg is not missing

I recall increasing the size of my mint partition (I'm duel booting it with windows), that's the only thing I can think of that could've done anything

Comment: @roaima I added the output of that command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can still run `dpkg`, at least part of the `dpkg` package is still present. To restore `dpkg-deb`, you should try re-installing `dpkg`:

- download [the appropriate package file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb) (Mint 18.3 is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so look for Xenial on [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg) to get the appropriate links; the download link I’m giving here assumes you’re using `amd64`)

  ```
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
  ```
- install it

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
  ```

If that fails, you’ll need to resort to a more manual approach as suggested in [arved’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536419/86440):

```
ar x dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb data.tar.gz
tar xf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg-deb
sudo install usr/bin/dpkg-deb /usr/bin
```

Then install the package using `dpkg` to make sure everything’s set up properly.

Comment: This worked!
Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Personally, I'd check what was going on with the `dpkg` package before reinstalling. `dpkg-deb` is part of it, and `--audit` should complain if files are missing.

Comment: @Faheem except that `--audit` doesn’t complain, for some reason I haven’t figured out yet. Try it: `sudo mv /usr/bin/dpkg-deb{,.moved}; dpkg -C; sudo mv /usr/bin/dpkg-deb{.moved,}`

Answer (score 2):

Add those directories (`/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`) to your user's PATH.

There's no harm in it and it's often useful - many "root" commands can provide useful info on things *you have read access to* even if they can't change anything because your non-root user doesn't have *write access*.

Alternatively, run `apt` with `sudo -i apt.....` instead of just `sudo apt.....`.  That will ensure the `apt` command gets run in a root **login** shell (so root's .profile or .bash_profile are executed, setting the PATH appropriately).

See `man sudo` and search for `-i` aka `--login` for details on what `-i` does.

Comment: I have them all of those on both my own user and root, and I can't install or delete anything from both of them, maybe I wasn't clear on that, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: can you add the output of `grep -i path /etc/sudoers` to your question? (root access is required for this).    Mine has `Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"` - this is the path used for every command run by `sudo` (unless, of course, over-ridden by a login shell's .profile/.bash_profile.  or if you're in the `exempt_group`).   See `man sudo` and search for `secure_path` for details.

Comment: Added the output @cas